# Are blocks mined in HyperLedger Fabric?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger

I have been reading the documentation on how HyperLedger Fabric's project is implementing a open source BlockChain solution: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/docs/protocol-spec.md

I have seen that PBFT consensus algorithm is used, but I do not understand how blocks are mined and shared among all Validating Peers in the BlockChain network.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Hyperledger Validating Peers (VPs) do not mine blocks and do not share the blocks between them. Here is how it works:

1. A transaction is send to one trusted VP.
2. The VP broadcasts the transaction to all other VPs.
3. All VPs reach consensus (using PBFT algorithm) on the order to follow to execute the transactions.
4. All VPs execute the transactions "on their own" following the total order and build a block (calculating hashes mainly) with the executed transactions.

All the blocks will be the same because: the transaction execution is deterministic (should be) and the number of tx in a block is fixed.

Comment: PBFT == practical byzantine fault tolerance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byzantine_fault_tolerance

Comment: Sounds similar to 2 phase commit protocol. Of course the resource manager and co ordinating manager wouldn't be that simple. Nevertheless, solutions leverage IBM z/OS RRS come to mind.

Comment: This is about step 3 above. Given that, the blockchain technology is founded on arriving at a consensus amongst Byzantine peers, why do VPs want consensus on the transactions order rather than the result of transactions? At least, in case of Bitcoin, the account balances are more important than the transactions order. http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/3871/6975

Comment: I would say that reaching consensus in the order is much easier than comparing the results of the transactions, given that the results of the transactions can be of multiple types (as chaincode allows all the operations defined in the chaincode itself, or the transaction can be just a query transaction).

Comment: @Marc Cayuela Rafols : If all the VPs running the same transactions then which block will merge into chain ?

Comment: @GokulaMurthy each VP has it's own chain, thus each VP will merge it into it's own chain (and as execution order was previously agreed by all VP, then all VP will end up in the same blockchain state).

Comment: @MarcCayuelaRafols but its unnecessary to execute the same transactions in all VPs right ? Also my question is " when the other authorized user raises a transaction to query some data from ledger from which VP's chain it will pull? "

Comment: @GokulaMurthy the user should always query a **trusted** VP.

Answer (score 9):

**According to Hyperledger Fabric 1.X**

1. User through Client SDK send the transaction proposal to Endorsing Peers.
2. Endorsing Peer check the transaction and make endorsement proposal of transaction(with read/write set (previous value/Changed value)) and send to again client SDK.
3. Client SDK wait for all endorsement, once it get all endorsement proposal it make one invocation request and send to Orderer.
4. Orderer verify invocation request rent by client SDK by checking Policies defined(Consensus), verify the transaction and add to the block.
5. According to configuration defined for block, after specified time or number of transaction it form a Hash of block by using transaction hash, metadata and previous block hash.
6. The blocks of transactions are “delivered” to all peers on the channel by the Orderer.
7. All committing peers verify the endorsing policy and ensure that there have been no changes to ledger state for read set variables since the read set was generated by the transaction execution. After this all the transactions in the block and update the ledger with new block and current state of asset.

Ledger Contains

- 1) Current state Database(Level BD or Couch DB)
- 2) Blockchain(Files)(Linked blocks)

[Read the transaction flow of hyperledger fabric](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/txflow.html)

Check image for reference[image: Hyperledger Fabric Transaction Flow]

Comment: Well explained @pavan Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 2):

Hyperledger is an umbrella of blockchain technologies.  Hyperledger Fabric, mentioned above, is one of them.  Hyperledger Sawtooth also does not use mining and adds these consensus algorithms:

- *PoET* Proof of Elapsed Time (optional Nakamoto-style consensus algorithm used for Sawtooth). PoET with SGX has BFT. PoET Simulator has CFT. Not CPU-intensive as with PoW-style algorithms, although it still can fork and have stale blocks . See PoET specification at https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/release s/latest/architecture/poet.html
- *RAFT* Consensus algorithm that elects a leader for a term of arbitrary time. Leader replaced if it times-out. Raft is faster than PoET, but is not BFT (Raft is CFT). Also Raft does not fork.
- With *unpluggable consensus*, another consensus algorithm can be changed without reinitializing the blockchain or even restarting the software.

For completeness, the original consensus algorithm with bitcoin (and *does* use mining) is:

- *PoW* Proof of Work. Completing work (CPU-intensive Nakamoto-style consensus algorithm). Usually used in permissionless blockchains