# Where are chaincodes executed?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger

Chaincodes represent the Smart Contracts in HyperLedger fabric blockchain. They can be called through transactions, but who executes the Chaincode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be confusing if the HyperLedger fabric project is compared to BitCoin because in BitCoin the blocks in the BlockChain have ultimately been executed by one node only (the one that solves the PoW problem first).

But HyperLedger fabric works in a different way [see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36844827/are-blocks-mined-in-hyperledger).

All Validating Peers (VPs) receive and execute all transactions after agreeing on total order of execution. Therefore, ChainCode sandboxes (that execute query and invoke transactions) exist in all VPs for every ChainCode deployed (sandboxes are killed after a period of inactivity, and they are restarted back if inactive ChainCode is invoked/queried again).