# How Hyperledger Fabric handle the Concurrent of "invoke" of the same Key-Value pair of chaincode?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain

For example, two applications are connecting one chaincode, if the action to request "invoke" of the same Key-Value pair of chaincode almost at the sametime, what will happen?

If it is nightmare for Hyperledger Fabric, how can we handle on it? on side of Hyperledger core.yaml setting? or side of chaincode design?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: The first answer was Fabric v0.6 related. **Fabric v1** uses a different mechanism. The steps are (to the best of my current knowledge):

1. Client sends transactions to Endorser(s).
2. Endorsers execute transaction, generating world state key / value change sets, which are called the Read/Write Set. Endorser(s) return result to client.
3. Client receives responses from all and compares result and R/W Set against endorsement policy.
4. Client forwards successful endorsement to ordering service, which creates blocks from a set of transactions.
5. Ordering service forwards complete block to all committers (endorsers, observers, and so on).
6. Each committer applies the transactions' R/W Sets in order, updating each read key's version as it goes along (uses a hashmap, obviously). While committing each set, it performs a check on each key's version in the read set such that the key version must not be less than the current version number.

NOTE: This is a **major change** from v0.6 in that only fully committed transactions can be seen by reads, even in the context of an invoke! If there is any key clash present, the transaction is **failed**, at the last minute! No chaincode events are emitted, but the failure is logged in the final block. World state changes are lost and the transaction must be resubmitted by the client!

The fix for this is to design your chaincode to **not** use shared keys for every asset, or to design your client to flow control API calls (chaincode events, whatever you want to call that) at the asset level, or most likely both.

The original question's answer is thus that the transactions both work fine on v0.6 Fabric and that the first transaction works but the second fails on Fabric v1 if the two are sent too closely together (and simultaneous is too close).

Obviously, when there is no key clash, both always work (assuming that the transaction passes consensus and is deterministic -- as in creating the same result on all endorsers).

Answer (score 2):

All the invoke and query transactions are executed sequentially (not concurrently). In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36844827/are-blocks-mined-in-hyperledger) it's explained how the transactions are executed. Observe that via consensus all executions are ordered and then each node executes them following that order. Therefore, there is no concurrency.

Comment: True for a single channel. However, transactions submitted simultaneously targeting the same or different chaincode on two channels can execute in parallel with no issues.